# Pairing elements in two matrices in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to pair up elements in two matrices, which are generated by the following code chunk:

```
    set.seed(29)
    y = rnorm(16)
    yn = paste('n', 1:16, sep='')
    y = embed(y, 3)
    yn = embed(yn, 3)
    ycomp = y[, rep(3, ncol(y))]
    yncomp = yn[, rep(3, ncol(y))]
    logitable = (ycomp - y) < 1
    yn[logitable] = NA
    yncomp[logitable] = NA
    yn
    #      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
    # [1,] NA    NA    NA
    # [2,] NA    NA    NA
    # [3,] "n5"  NA    NA
    # [4,] NA    "n5"  NA
    # [5,] NA    NA    NA
    # [6,] "n8"  "n7"  NA
    # [7,] NA    NA    NA
    # [8,] NA    NA    NA
    # [9,] NA    NA    NA
    #[10,] NA    NA    NA
    #[11,] NA    NA    NA
    #[12,] "n14" "n13" NA
    #[13,] NA    NA    NA
    #[14,] NA    NA    NA
    yncomp
    #      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
    # [1,] NA    NA    NA
    # [2,] NA    NA    NA
    # [3,] "n3"  NA    NA
    # [4,] NA    "n4"  NA
    # [5,] NA    NA    NA
    # [6,] "n6"  "n6"  NA
    # [7,] NA    NA    NA
    # [8,] NA    NA    NA
    # [9,] NA    NA    NA
    #[10,] NA    NA    NA
    #[11,] NA    NA    NA
    #[12,] "n12" "n12" NA
    #[13,] NA    NA    NA
    #[14,] NA    NA    NA
```

The expected result would be a matrix with 2 columns like this

```
    "n3" "n5"
    "n4" "n5"
    "n6" "n7"
    "n6" "n8"
    "n12" "n14"
    "n12" "n13"
```

---

Edit: Added the quotation marks to avoid confusion. :)

Comment: are the two matrices always not `NA` for the same indexes?

Comment: Yeah, I deliberately made it that way, and in reality it will be like this in my project. :)

Comment: And is there any particular rhyme or reason to the ordering in your expected result?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Order is not important in the result, as long as the pairing is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a two-column matrix as the result (instead of a vector of comma-separated values), you could use this approach:

```
both <- cbind(as.vector(yncomp), as.vector(yn))
both[!is.na(both[, 1]), ]
```

Comment: you can use `c` instead of `as.vector`, for succintness :-)

Comment: Wonderful. I am thinking why I haven't thought of this!

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, that would be using `c` for a side-effect, but not necessarily an intended use.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the resulting pairs as a list of vectors :

```
result <- mapply(c, yncomp, yn, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
result[! is.na(names(result))]

# $n3
# [1] "n3" "n5"
# 
# $n6
# [1] "n6" "n8"
# 
# $n12
# [1] "n12" "n14"
# 
# $n4
# [1] "n4" "n5"
# 
# $n6
# [1] "n6" "n7"
# 
# $n12
# [1] "n12" "n13"
```